# Meteor.js find() helper not affecting page

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to create 2 views. One that will show the user all of their submissions by finding their user id and filtering for it. The other will show everyone. But when I use this it still shows everyone. Any ideas?

```
Template.myapps.helpers({
    NetworkApps: ()=> {
        return NetworkApp.find({applicant: Meteor.userId});
    }
});
```

I have even replaced the `applicant: Meteor.userId` with `ign: 'dkafdklsf'` which in theory would return nothing but it is returning all entries.

Comment: Firstly it's `Meteor.userId()` but besides that please show your `myapps` template html code.

Comment: And please also add the code of your publication method.